# Are there animals in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was wondering, are there animals in GTA  Online? I haven't really paid any attention. I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: Asking something like this out of the blue because you "haven't really been paying attention" is not going to be very well received around here. Was there anything that may have indicated to you that there might be animals in GTA Online?

Comment: @Unionhawk Why shouldn't there be animals? If there are animals in the SP, why not in MP?

Comment: @Mathias711 (I know I'm trying to let the asker figure that out on their own)

Comment: @Unionhawk someone told me tht he died cuz a bird hit him in GTA V Online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are not any animals in GTA-online, according to different sources [[1]](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202699643-Why-is-there-no-animals-in-gta-online-ps4)[[2]](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/733724-grand-theft-auto-online/67496493). However, there are plans for mods that will add the missing animals [[3]](http://mp1st.com/2014/01/07/modders-bring-wildlife-gta-online/#.VYaap1WqpBc). But I couldn't find anything that Rockstar is planning on adding those animals.

Comment: I think they added animals in the next-gen versions (PC, PS4, and XBOX One) of GTA Online

Answer (score 0):

I think there was talk of animals online when they announced GTA for the new gen. I don't know about PC but as far as I'm aware on PS4 and Xbox One sharks are the only animals and they are quite rare.

Answer (score 0):

There are animals in gta online there is that one thing you ca eat that turns you into an animal.  Also when you are swimming sometimes you may run into a shark or swim into one either/or.

Answer (score -1):

On PS3/Xbox 360, There were animals in GTA 5 Online for a sort period. However, they were taken out due to server capacity.